# Shell script to run Linux command on multiple servers command by command

Tags: linux, shell

I have a scenario:

My system has 2 servers: `server_A` and `server_B`

On `server_A` I create a shell script to execute commands on `server_A` and `server_B` by this flow:

1. Run `command1` on `server_A` and wait for completion.
2. Run `command2` on `server_B` and wait for completion.
3. Run `command3` on `server_A` and wait for completion.

(etc.)

Is there any good solutions for this case?

Thank you a lot.

Comment: You want to commands on alternating servers? Where do the commands come from? Will they be interactive, or are they static?

Comment: >You want to commands on alternating servers? Yes

>Where do the commands come from? Using a shell script file on Server_A (or another server is ok) to execute commands on Server_A and B.

>Will they be interactive, or are they static? They are static

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just make a script on server_A with :

```
command1

ssh server_B command2

command 3
```

Comment: But for each ssh command, server_B will ask server_A for the password to execute the command. How to skip this step? Thank you.

Comment: @TuanPham ssh has a mechanism of key pair authentication, see for example : https://debian-administration.org/article/530/SSH_with_authentication_key_instead_of_password